# carregar data hora sem javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

Queria saber se é possível enviar direto do controller, por exemplo a data e hora atual do sistema sem usar javascript. Ex:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataAvaliacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataAvaliacao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataAvaliacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
// GET: Avaliacao
public ActionResult Create()
{
    DateTime data = DateTime.Now;//Essa data ao carregar a tela aparece para o usuário
    return View();
}
```

Tipo como se fosse a `Viewbag` e ai na hora que a tela carregar, aparecer a data e hora

Comment: Com `ViewBag` !!!

Answer (score 0):

Bom você pode passar este objeto por uma **ViewBag** ou através do seu **model**, a baixo segue o exemplo de como fazer destas duas formas, sendo o primeiro exemplo a demonstração de utilização da **Viewbag**.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Data = DateTime.Now;
    return View();
}
```

feito isto basta acessar a viewbag na sua View

Em seu html/razor você pode simplesmente fazer assim se quiser exibir o valor da data

```
<strong> @ViewBag.Data </strong>
```

Caso você tenha interesse em colocar esta data como o valor **padrão** do seu campo DataAvaliacao. Uma opção é inicializar o objeto referente ao model no controller, preenche-lo, e em seguida envia-lo para a view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{ 
    var model = new SeuTipoDeObjeto();
    model.DataAvaliacao = DateTime.Now;
    return View(model);
}
```

Desta forma o valor do seu textbox será preenchido com a data atual.

Answer (score 0):

já tentou no Razor ?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataAvaliacao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = DateTime.Now/*.ToShortDateString()*/ } })
```